# Initialize multidimensional vector with fixed value

Tags: c++, stl

I'm creating a multidimensional vector as follows,

```
vector< vector<int> > vec(10, vector<int>(15));
```

How do I assign a fixed value to all elements in the vector?

Comment: [Use the appropriate constructor.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(10, std::vector<int>(15, fixed_value));
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ad923c844db2aff)

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below:

```
int val = 5;
vector< vector<int> > vec(10, vector<int>(15,val));
```

It can be any value, if you do not want to use variable.